# Simple select query hangs

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT a.name AS a_name,
       b.description AS b_description
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
    WHERE b.table_name IS NULL;
```

(Names changed to protect the innocent)

This usually takes ~3ms to run. Sometimes, this query hangs. It has currently been hanging for 3 days. Luckily, I'm in a position where I can try and debug this in its current state, for a while. It appears there's nothing blocking it (found by querying pg_locks and pg_stat_activity), though it is blocking other things.

Even with the other query in a hung state, I can run the same query again, and it completes successfully in the expected time period.

Things that are likely to be involved: we currently have two cron jobs (don't ask) that dump the database. I can find the exact commands being run if it's likely to be relevant.

Any suggestions on how to debug this gratefully received!

Comment: Try to rewrite the query to NOT EXISTS.

Comment: for the query to hang for 3 days I suspect something else is going on...   Is the session sitting idle or is it still chunking away 100% cpu usage??

Comment: Can you find it in pg_stat_activity?  What do you see for wait_event_type , wait_event , state

Answer (score 4):

Check the wait events in `pg_stat_activity` to see if your query is running or hanging.

In the latter case, examine `pg_locks` or use the `pg_blocking_pids` function to see which session blocks you.

If no locks are involved, see if the backend process consumes CPU or not. Optionally use `strace` to see what the backend is doing.